# Lightbox2 v2.6 has 0.8 opacity and close button missing

Tags: lightbox2

I am trying to find out why my Lightbox is not showing 0.8 opacity and no close button or outer container for the image.    I do get a black background and the image.  I, to the best of my knowledge, followed the instructions.  Here is a link to my page,  http://www.crawfordcountyhistoricalsociety.org/Pages/Sale.html  only the first item for sale is set for lightbox.
I am using Dreamweaver CS4 and have a template for the pages to keep the banner,background and footer the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have the paths to your jQuery, lightbox js, img and css files incorrect. They're pointing to `crawfordcountyhistoricalsociety.org/Pages/`, while it looks like they're actually located at `crawfordcountyhistoricalsociety.org/`. Try changing your import lines in the page source from:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

To:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
<link href="/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

(In other words add a leading slash to indicate they're at the root of your folder structure)

Comment: That did the trick.  It still does not work when testing on my local drive, but it works when uploaded.  Thanks